# GRUB prompt at boot after boot-repair

Tags: 12.04, grub2, boot-failure

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 from the live CD. The install went fine but i had the next error while booting :

```
Grub stage 1.5 error 2.
```

So I used boot-repair as explained [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair). Still not working, i got this while booting :

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3
```

Minimal bash-like line editing is supported.

etc.. Nothing more.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1408117) the report from boot-repair.

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

For one it sounds like it's a fresh install so in that case try reinstalling ubuntu. Now the other thing I noticed your running GRUB 1.99, by default I believe 12.04 installs GRUB 2 so if you have manually changed GRUB that would likely be your issue or perhaps you installed the wrong version when doing the boot-repair. In any case try a reinstall.